# Помощь в улучшении алгоритма

Tags: python, алгоритм

Есть двумерный массив размера N*M (пример N = 4, M = 3)

```
[1, 0, 0]

[1, 1, 0]

[0, 1, 0]

[0, 0, 2]
```

нужно получить сумму произведений элементов в массиве длины М удовлетворяющих требованию
`arr[i][j], arr[k][x], arr[q][p]` где `i<k<q и j<x<p`

в примере удовлетворяют условию группы элементов

```
arr[0][0],arr[1][1],arr[3][2] 1,1,2 прозведени 2
arr[0][0],arr[2][1],arr[3][2] 1,1,2 прозведени 2
arr[1][0],arr[2][1],arr[3][2] 1,1,2 прозведени 2
```

я написал программу с временной сложностью O(M * N* M)

```
def dfs(row,col,arr,p):
    if col == len(arr[0]):
        return p
    s = 0
    while row < len(arr):
        s+=dfs(row+1,col+1,arr,p*arr[row][col])
        row+=1
    return s
dfs(0,0,arr,1)
```

Но есть чувство что его можно улучшить до O(M * N) с помощью динамического программирования. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Оставить в `dfs` только параметры `row` и `col` и закешировать.

Comment: Чем группа arr[0][0],arr[1][1],arr[2][2] не подходит? Условие `удовлетворяющих требованию` выглядит недописанным

Comment: @MBo вангую, потом что там произведение 0 будет

Comment: @tym32167 верно!

Comment: Но в условии об этом не написано.

Comment: `с временной сложностью O(M * N* M)` вы уверены, что у вас именно такая временная сложность? Вы перебираете все возможные пути. То есть в первом шаге вы перебираете N строк, потом но второй глубине рекурсии опять N строк, потом опять N строк, то есть у вас вроде как N**M (N в степени M) сложность просто потому что вы перебираете все возможные пути в графе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*f<sub>i,j</sub>* - искомая сумма произведений для матрицы *[0, i] × [0, j]*. Тогда

- *f<sub>i,-1</sub> = 1*
- *f<sub>i,j</sub> = 0*, если *i < j*
- *f<sub>i,j</sub> = a<sub>i,j</sub>·f<sub>i-1,j-1</sub> + f<sub>i-1,j</sub>* - первое слагаемое для всех последовательностей, которые заканчиваются в углу  *a<sub>i,j</sub>*, второе для тех которые заканчиваются раньше.

```
import functools


def f(a):

    @functools.cache
    def f(i, j):
        if j == 0:
            return 1
        if i < j:
            return 0
        return a[i][j] * f(i - 1, j - 1) + f(i - 1, j)

    return f(len(a) - 1, len(a[0]) - 1)


print(f([
    [1, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 2]
]))
```

Сложность *O(nm)*: благодаря кешу для каждой пары *(i, j)* *f* вычисляется один раз. Сложность одного вызова - константа. Могут быть проблемы с глубиной рекурсии. Тогда сделаем ручное кеширование:

```
def f(a):

    f = [[None] * len(r) for r in a]

    f[0][0] = a[0][0]
    for j in range(1, len(a[0])):
        f[0][j] = 0

    for i in range(1, len(a)):
        f[i][0] = a[i][0] + f[i - 1][0]
        for j in range(1, len(a[i])):
            f[i][j] = a[i][j] * f[i - 1][j - 1] + f[i - 1][j]

    return f[-1][-1]


print(f([
    [1, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 2]
]))
```

Можно заметить что следующая строка кеша зависит только от предыдущей. Можно обойтись памятью *O(m)*:

```
def f(a):
    f_row = [1] + [0] * len(a[0])
    for a_row in a:
        for j in reversed(range(len(a_row))):
            f_row[j + 1] += a_row[j] * f_row[j]
    return f_row[-1]


print(f([
    [1, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 2]
]))
```

Comment: меня в уравнении `f[i][j] = a[i][j] * f[i - 1][j - 1] + f[i - 1][j]` смущает немного последняя часть `+ f[i - 1][j]` - как она получилась? Если это все  суммы заканчиваюзщиеся столбцом выше, разве их не надо поделить на `a[i][j-1]` и умножить на `a[i][j]`?

Comment: @tym32167, *f_i,j* определена как сумма всех маршрутов. Часть маршрутов завершается не доходя до *i*. За них и отвечает *f_i-1,j*. Обратите внимание *f_i,j* включает не только маршруты с концом в *(i,j)*, а вообще все маршруты которые можно нарисовать в прямоугольнике *i * j*.

Comment: я не понял, у вас i - это столбец, а j - строка? Просто если маршут закаечивается в том же стобце, только выше строкой - он до текущей ячейки и не дойдет никогда

Comment: опа, так, понял про сумму маршрутов, то есть теперь `+ f[i - 1][j]` имеет смысл. И вот это вроде `a[i][j] * f[i - 1][j - 1]` тогда встало на место. Красиво, придется ставить плюс =)

Comment: *i* - номер строки, *j* - номер столбца. Когда маршрут заканчивается выше *i*, он попадает в *f_i-1,j*, *f_i,j*, *f_i+1,j* и т.д.

Comment: да да, я понял. Я у себя считал суммы которые только заканчиваются в ячейке, а у вас суммы всех путей во всем прямоугольнике `i,j` - вот как я понял это, сразу дошло решение

Comment: @tym32167, "придется ставить плюс" - :). Спасибо что ставите плюсы только за дело. :)

Comment: хах, да, я ставлю только за дело, это первый мой плюс в этом году!  

Answer (score 1):

Я бы решал через DP, то есть

1. создал бы массив той же размерности
2. в каждой ячейке массива писал бы сумму всех произведений, что в этой ячейке заканчиваются.

То есть изначальный массив

```
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 2]
```

DP массив поначалу забитый нулями

```
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
```

Первый столбец от 0 строки до len-2 строки просто проставляем равным изначальнму (первые шаги путей)

```
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
```

Второй столбец от 1 строки до len-1 строки - суммируем все возможные произведения для второго столбца

```
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0]
[0, 1*1+1*1, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
```

Третий столбец от 2 строки до len строки - делаем то же самое для третьего столбца (тут важно понимать, что для нахождения сумм третьего столбца нам нужен только второй столбец, первый уже не нужен)

```
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0]
[0, 2, 0]
[0, 0, 2*1 + 2*2]
```

Суммируем третий столбец (там уже все суммы произведений всех путей для каждой ячейки)

```
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0]
[0, 2, 0]
[0, 0, 6]
```

сумма третьего столбца = 6

Вот и всё по сути. Поскольку на каждой итерации мы для каждой ячейки перебираем весь следующий стоблец (N*N), и таких переборов у нас будет столько, сколько столбцов (M), то суммарная сложность алгоритма будет `M*N*N`(то есть `M*(N**2)`)

Код на C# (я питонов ваших не умею) получился бы примерно такой

```cs
int SumOfMult(int[,] data)
{
    int N = data.GetLength(0);
    int M = data.GetLength(1);

    var dp = new int[N, M];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        dp[i, 0] = data[i, 0];
        for (int j = 0; j < M - 1; j++)
            for (int k = i + 1; k < N; k++)
                dp[k, j + 1] += data[k, j + 1] * dp[i, j];
    }

    int ret = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) ret += dp[i, M - 1];
    return ret;
}
```

Сложность вышла M*N*N, но если чуть чуть подшаманить, можно получить N*N*N при условии, если M>N

Проверка

```
Console.WriteLine(SumOfMult(new[,] {
    { 1, 0, 0 },
    { 1, 1, 0 },
    { 0, 1, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 2} }));
```

Вывод

```
6
```

Comment: Спасибо.  Но явно можно быстрее)

Comment: Очень в этом сомневаюсь, но если вы покажете как - буду благодарен =)

Comment: о, поглядел соседний ответ, точно, можно за N*M, класс!

Comment: добавили решение, отметил его как принятый